# R textmining build a corpus structured with subsets of a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, text-mining, tm, word-cloud

I'm new in formulas with R and I'm struggling quite a bit to change some repetitive code into something more compact. As suggested in the comment of MrFlick, I posted the working solution I've already found in the answers section.

So my problem is to create various corpuses for a comparative wordcloud using several different categorisations, as you can see here in [wikispiral.org](https://wikispiral.org/tiki-index.php?page=CG%20Facilitators%20-%20Semantic_exploration&CGname=Braine%20l%27Alleud). For this I need to create a list of character vectors based on subsets of the original dataframe (given categories present in the dataframe). See the following example:

```
library(wordcloud)
library(tm)

element <- c("Adams Pearmain ", "Aia Ilu ", "Airlie Red Flesh", "Akane ", "Åkerö ", "Alkmene", "Allington Pippin ", "Ambrosia ", "Anna ", "Annurca ", "Antonovka ", "Apollo ", "Ariane ", "Arkansas Black ", "Arthur Turner")
qty <- c(2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 2, 1, 4, 3, 6)
category1 <- c("Red", "Green", "Red", "Green", "Yellow", "Orange", "Red", "Red", "Green", "Red", "Green", "Yellow",  "Green", "Yellow", "Orange")
category2 <- c("small", "big", "big", "small", "small", "medium", "medium", "medium", big", "big", "small", "medium", "big", "very big", "medium")
d <- data.frame(element=element, qty=qty, category1=category1, category2=category2)
```

Which gives this dataframe :

```
    element             qty category1   category2
1   Adams Pearmain      2   Red         small
2   Aia Ilu             1   Green       big
3   Airlie Red Flesh    4   Red         small
4   Akane               3   Green       big
5   Åkerö               6   Yellow      small
6   Alkmene             2   Orange      big
7   Allington Pippin    1   Red         small
8   Ambrosia            4   Red         big
9   Anna                3   Green       small
10  Annurca             6   Red         big
11  Antonovka           2   Green       small
12  Apollo              1   Yellow      big
13  Ariane              4   Green       small
14  Arkansas Black      3   Yellow      big
15  Arthur Turner       6   Orange      big
```

I am currently creating my list of vectors for wordcloud  as such:

```
## Subsetting two dataframes to category2 values
wordBig <- d[d$category2 == "big",]
wordSmall <- d[d$category2 == "small",]

## Extracting the vectors in the category1 columns
wordSmall <- as.vector(wordSmall$category1)
wordBig <- as.vector(wordBig$category1)

## Building the list for the corpus
wordALL <- list(wordBig, wordSmall) # Without list() it doesn' t work
```

And finally:

corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(wordALL), readerControl = list(language = "fr"))

In my real life example in [wikispiral.org](https://wikispiral.org/tiki-index.php?page=CG%20Facilitators%20-%20Semantic_exploration&CGname=Braine%20l%27Alleud), there is a dynamic array of dimensions - not only the categories "big" or "small" (and some of those categories are defined by the users of the website, and are quite unpredictable). Even for the fixed categories the code was getting repetitive and ugly, and each dimension's existence had to be tested in order to avoid an error `comparative.wordcloud()` produces if there is NAs in a category (like no data in the "big" category).

So my question is: how to transform the precedent example in a more compact code, which is able to:
1 - detect the categories in the classification column
2 - build the list of character vectors
3 - Perhaps do this avoiding loops...

I' ve already found an answer that I have put in the answers section following MrFlick's advice.

Comment: Request for code review belong on [codereview.se], not Stack Overflow. It would be better to edit your question to focus on a specific programming question. Rather than asking others to review your solution, you can paste is as an answer where others can vote if they agree or post alternative solutions.

Comment: Use `split` with a second argument of `d$category2` to create a list of "sub-data.frames" and then work in those subsets.

Comment: Thanks for your comments both helped a lot, as you can see in my answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, following 42's suggestion in his comment, it is indeed quicker and cleaner...

```
listtest <- split(d,d$category2)
listtest <- lapply(listtest, droplevels.data.frame)
wordALL <- lapply(listtest, "[[", "element")
```

And there it is, a list of factors, from a dataframe, ready to build a corpus:

```
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(wordALL), readerControl = list(language = "fr"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a function to build this list using a for loop which subsets the character vectors from the main dataframe and populates the list. I updated my function in order for it to be more generic, so others can reuse it to help build their applications.

```
CorpusFromDF <- function(DF, textcol, catcol) {
  # DF = a dataframe 
  # wordcol = the name of a column from DF containing the text to build the corpus
  # catcol = the name of a column from DF containing the categorisation
  cat <- levels(DF[,catcol])
  list <- list()
  for (n in cat){
    temp <- DF[DF[,catcol] == n,]
    temp <- as.vector(temp[,textcol])
    list <- append(list, list(temp))
    }
  return(list)
}
```

And to use it:

```
wordALL <- CorpusFromDF(d, "element", "category2")
```

So I' m really happy because it works (it is my first R function after all), I have what I need, a list of vectors containing the words. From there I can reuse this to reshape my corpuses especially in order to build network analysis texmining using several different categories/classifications.

But it is perfectible and I'm guessing that there might be a possibility without the use of loops especially when you have really a lot of categories to build your corpus... What will be my case for other applications...